# KDE Service Menus get list of selected files in selected order

Tags: scripts, kubuntu, kde, pdf, dolphin

I try to add an Service Menu Action to dolphin to combine selected pdf-files with pdfunite.

It works so far. Now I am stuck, because I want to select the order, in which the files are concatenated. But instead of the selection order, it uses the order of appearance in dolphin.

In this example, I want to combine the files as follows: test_firstpage.pdf, test_secondpage.pdf, test_lastpage.pdf
[image]

But the script gets the files in the order which is shown in dolphin - **not the manual selected order**. So in this Case: test_firstpage.pdf, test_lastpage.pdf, test_secondpage.pdf

How is it possible to get the files in den manual selected order?

The desktop-File with the menu configuration:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Icon=dialog-ok
Type=Service
X-KDE-ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
MimeType=application/pdf;
Actions=unitePDFFiles
X-KDE-Submenu=Unite PDF Files
   
[Desktop Action unitePDFFiles]
Name=PDF Unite
Name[de]=PDF zusammenführen
Icon=document-new
Exec=/bin/sh -c "<snip>/pdfunite_menu.sh %F"
```

The script pdfunite_menu.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Desktop-File with menu configuration:
# ~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/unitePDF.desktop
# Documentation:
# https://develop.kde.org/docs/dolphin/service-menus/
    
path=
files=
for f in $*
do
        # print the order of the files in a log
        echo "Parameter:  $f " >> pdfunite_menu.log
        files="$files $f"
done
pdfunite $files pdfunite_`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S`.pdf
```

Comment: I did a few experiments with the %U argument it seems, that the files are passed with the order they are sorted in dolphin. My exec line looks like this : `Exec=pdftk %U cat output "$(dirname "%u")/united.pdf"`. I understand you have already seen that. However, I do not see an alternative here https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s07.html